# Convert a column of dates of a pandas dataframe to the last date of the respective year

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I have a pandas dataframe, lets call it `df`, looking like this:

```
    Acount              Type   Id               Date         Value          Per
0   Exp                 P      IQ               2016-03-31  -23421.170324   3M
1   Exp                 P      IQ               2017-03-31  -44803.599908   3M
2   Exp                 P      IQ               2018-03-31  -29294.611346   3M
3   Exp                 P      IQ               2019-03-31  -9463.281704    3M
```

I need the date column to have the last day of each year, for example: "2019/12/31" and `df` to look like this:

```
    Acount              Type   Id               Date         Value          Per
0   Exp                 P      IQ               2016-12-31  -23421.170324   3M
1   Exp                 P      IQ               2017-12-31  -44803.599908   3M
2   Exp                 P      IQ               2018-12-31  -29294.611346   3M
3   Exp                 P      IQ               2019-12-31  -9463.281704    3M
```

Do you guys know what do I have to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`pd.offsets.YearEnd`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.YearEnd.html):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']) + pd.offsets.YearEnd(0)
```

Output:

```
  Acount Type  Id       Date         Value Per
0    Exp    P  IQ 2016-12-31 -23421.170324  3M
1    Exp    P  IQ 2017-12-31 -44803.599908  3M
2    Exp    P  IQ 2018-12-31 -29294.611346  3M
3    Exp    P  IQ 2019-12-31  -9463.281704  3M
```

Answer (score 1):

**Example**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['2016-03-31', '2017-03-31', '2018-03-31'], columns=['Date'])
```

`df`

```
    Date
0   2016-03-31
1   2017-03-31
2   2018-03-31
```

---

**Code**

```
df['Date'].astype('Period[Y]').dt.to_timestamp(freq='Y')
```

`result`:

```
0   2016-12-31
1   2017-12-31
2   2018-12-31
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```